# Creating a new email from an Excel Add In

Tags: office-js

I have an excel add in that I'd like the user to be able to send an email from.  I could use mailto: but it's likely the amount of content to send would exceed the limits for that.

Ideally, it would be nice if I could somehow invoke the local outlook client with the content in a similar way and then allow the user to have the final say on hitting send.  I suspect this isn't possible though?

Failing that I guess I'd need to use the Microsoft Graph API which adds a lot of unnecessary complexity to it since I assume I would then have to sort out the authentication along with the UI for sending the email.

Any thoughts anyone has that might help simplify this greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you summarized the options. There is no way to invoke local Outlook client through the add-in as Excel add-in is sandboxed and can't access local executable. Doing this through Microsoft Graph is the best way. At this point [single-sign-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) feature is still in beta. If you need to deploy this to production, you will have to invoke the OAuth2 flow (dialog to get user consent). That is not much of work given there are plenty of samples on-line. Once single sign-on is available in GA, the flow becomes easy and you don't need the extra consent step.